# Slack API TIme out error

Tags: slack-api

I am getting "The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server" error from Slack API.Can any one explain the reason? And what is the timeout of Slack server?

Answer (score 2):

Websocket connections can fail for a number of reasons - Slack server failure, Slack updating their software, the team has uninstalled your app, the Gods of Internet have decided you needed to be punished, and so on.

When that happens, your app should try to reconnect. If the error is something along the line of 'invalid_token', it'll mean your app has been uninstalled from the team. Otherwise, the connection should be able to reconnect.

How quickly and how many times you should try to reconnect is another matter. Usually, frameworks provide sensible defaults. What do you use?